# while installing atom i am getting this error !!what should i do to fix this error?

Tags: windows, atom-editor, appdata

7-11-19 12:38:57> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
2017-11-19 12:38:57> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\default.LAPTOP-L777RA0L\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-11-19 12:38:57> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\default.LAPTOP-L777RA0L\AppData\Local\atom
2017-11-19 12:38:58> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\default.LAPTOP-L777RA0L\AppData\Local\atom\packages.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to come from a **too long paths**.

I encountered the same problem on windows, try to delete the content of **%LOCALAPPDATA%/Temp** then try to install again.

If it does not work, download the [zip version](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.28.2).

Source [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5767)